# Should jobs within jobs use perform_later or perform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

I'm calling `ExampleJob.perform_later` in an action. This job is in turn calling two other jobs (see below).

Should these as well have the method `perform_later` or `perform` or doesn't it matter?

```
class ExampleJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    Example2Job.perform_later
    Example3Job.perform_later
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want your jobs to be performed asynchronously, you should use `perform_later`. Otherwise you can use `Job.new.perform` or `Job.perform_now`

Comment: So despite that the encapsulating job has `perform_later`, the two nested jobs will trump that and the jobs will be run synchronously?

Comment: No, no. The encapsulating job will run async, the question is whether you want your nested jobs to be performed inline in the same thread/process as encapsulating job or you want them to run separatly

Comment: Alright I get it. So `perform_later` sounds like the most recommendable.

Comment: Yeah, unless Example3Job depends on result from Example2Job